# Como crear un respaldo y como restaurarlo

Tags: sql-server

estoy programando en C# con base de datos SQL server, Necesito crear un respaldo de la base de datos y  restaurarla desde el respaldo, desconozco si hay algún comando en SQL o si como he visto en algunas paginas se hace a través de  "Cmd.exe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL Server tienes el comando Backup Database

```
BACKUP DATABASE MiBaseDeDatos
TO DISK = 'C:\mibasededatos.BAK'
GO
```

Así mismo, puedes restaurarla con el comando RESTORE DATABASE

```
RESTORE DATABASE MiBaseDeDatos 
FROM DISK = 'C:\mibasededatos.BAK'
```

Si tienes instalado SQL Server Management Studio, puedes hacerlo desde la interfaz gráfica.

Comment: Disculpa no manejo bien los formatos para responder mas ordenado, trate con el comando para crear el BACKUP y me aparece lo siguiente:
https://ibb.co/r2pTmG4   espero que no haya problema por adjuntar una foto de esa forma

Comment: @Milepls crea una carpeta dentro de C: y ahí coloca el archivo .BAK

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahi si me funciono el BACKUP,  el RESTORE me da este error https://ibb.co/8KsYvt2 supongo que es porque necesitaria  Borrar la BD antes de restaurarla

Comment: Exacto @Milepls, aunque puedes agregar la opción WITH REPLACE para sobreescribir la BD si ya existe, del siguiente modo: RESTORE DATABASE MiBaseDeDatos 
FROM DISK = 'C:\mibasededatos.BAK' WITH REPLACE